# Rule Engine based on hierarchical matching

Tags: python, algorithm, matching, rule-engine

Say, I have a dataset (cities) with this structure:

- ID
- City
- State
- Country
- Continent

And I have a configuration table (key, value) where the key can be a combination of above parameters

For eg:

```
{
    "continent": "asia"
}
```

or

```
{
    "continent": "asia",
    "country" : "india"
}
```

or

```
{
    "continent": "asia",
    "country" : "india",
    "state" : "maharashtra",
    "city" : "mumbai"
}
```

Now, I want to do a closest match of cities from the 1st dataset to the entries in configuration.

For example, if I have

```
city: mumbai, state: maharashtra, country: india, continent: asia
```

it should match, 3rd entry in the config above.

If I have

```
city: tokyo, state: Kantō, country: japan, continent: asia
```

it should match 1st entry in the config above.

I am looking for suggestions if something is readily available for this kind of a scenario.

I am open to storing the configurations in some different way if there is any.

Ideally I would like a solution in which I can pass *multiple* entries (inputs) and it should return the closest matching configuration for each of the inputs.

Comment: It is not clear. What if you have both tokyo and mumbai entries in your data, what is the expected output? Should it output the third config item (the object), or the index of the config in the list of configs (is there such a thing?). Please provide a completely worked out example (multiple data, multiple config, the *literal* output you expect....)

Comment: It would also be useful to know which part is the fixed part: the configs, or the data entries? Which of the two are the more dynamic growing collections?

Comment: I updated the last line of the question, if it would make it more clearer. The question is simple: For each of the input I pass to the function, it should return the closest possible config. Config table has 2 columns (key is the json key and you can assume value is some weighing factor)

Comment: Both config and cities would be in database, but you could assume both don't change that frequently, but they can. Config might have, say, 1000-3000 entries. And the dataset can have many, but, we would call the function for, say, batch of 100-200 . So for now you can assume, the dataset is in memory and the config is in database table

Comment: So, if you call the function with a batch of 100 data entries, you would expect a return value of exactly 100 results: the best matching config entry per input... So actually when you have a function that can only take one data entry and return the best matching config item, that would also do it, as you would just call it 100 times, once per data entry. Do I get it right? It would have been much more simple to understand if you had a worked out example of what the function would have as *inputs*, and what as *outputs*, together with your attempt at it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Instead of calling the function 100 times, i was thinking if it was possible to do in terms of db query, wherein we pass a list of inputs, query the config table by parameterizing the where clause, and it returns the best possible match for each input.

Comment: It is the first time you mention "db query". Is that essential to your question?

Comment: sorry for that, but it is not essential. I am looking for options. I can read the config db once and store the config in memory as a collection and the write a function which accepts list of inputs and returns list of outputs by referring to the in memory config collection.

Comment: Did you have a look at my answer? I think it offers such a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the risk that I misunderstand the question, I would:

- collect configuration entries in a tree-like data structure, for faster retrieval
- find a match for a single data entry at a time, by traversing through that tree

Here is how that would look:

```py
class Config:
    def __init__(self):
        self.continents = {}

    def add(self, config):
        collection = self.continents
        for prop in ["continent", "country", "state", "city"]:
            if prop not in config:
                break
            key = config[prop]
            if key not in collection:
                collection[key] = {}
            collection = collection[key]
        collection["config"] = config

    def get(self, data):
        collection = self.continents
        config = None
        for prop in ["continent", "country", "state", "city"]:
            if prop not in data or data[prop] not in collection:
                break
            collection = collection[data[prop]]
            if "config" in collection:
                config = collection["config"]
        return config
```

The above class can be used as follows.

First create an instance, and populate it with configuration entries:

```py
config = Config()

config.add({ "continent": "asia"})
config.add({ "continent": "asia", "country": "india" })
config.add({ "continent": "asia", "country": "india", 
             "state": "maharashtra", "city": "mumbai" })
```

Then iterate your data entries, and for each call `config.get` to get the best matching configuration. For example:

```
print(config.get({ "city": "mumbai", "state": "maharashtra", 
                   "country": "india", "continent": "asia"}))

print(config.get({"city": "tokyo", "state": "kantō", 
                   "country": "japan", "continent": "asia"}))
```